# Beta testing an iPhone app with TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

Currently I'm using [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) to push beta versions. If I change the `provisioning profile` (by adding a new user's `deviceID`) do I need to then push a new build, or will the new user's `deviceID` be automatically recozniged by the existing provisioning profile on the app. I'm guessing the former...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the former. The provisioning profile is bundled with your app and there's no way for iOS to get the new provisioning profile otherwise.

Comment: That is funky. Without testflight this does not apply as the profile is not bundled with the app - or better said, the device ids are not. Hence the need to deliver the profile separately.

Comment: Right, if you were setting up your own OTA delivery you could specify the provisioning profile to use along with supplying the ipa. But with TestFlight you only upload an ipa. So the provisioning profile has to be bundled with it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to push the new build through TestFlight when ever you added the new device for that particular Provisioning profile, then only yow will find the new device ID in the list (teammates list)so that you can give the permissions accordingly,otherwise you can't.